# Can the logarithm of the sum of random variables be decomposed into the sum of independent random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, gamma-distribution

Suppose $X1$ and $X2$ are two independent **Gamma** random variables, both follow Gamma distribution **but different scales (or rates),** their shape can be same or different.

Let $Z$ be another random variable, the **logarithm of the sum** of $X1, X2$:

$Z = log(X1 + X2)$

**Question**: Can $Z$ be decomposed into the summation of two **independent** random variables (required to be NOT constants) ? In other words, can we find independent random variables $Y1, Y2$ such that

$Z = Y1 + Y2$

If answer is YES, how to find such decomposition ?

Thank you.